# Pandas gbq load - to_gbq timeout exception

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

anyone has a clue about this error:

> {u'kind': u'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse', u'insertErrors':
>   [{u'index': 90, u'errors': [{u'reason': u'timeout'}]},

I am trying to execute:

```
from pandas.io import gbq

df.to_gbq(tablename, project_id=projectid)
```

df - is a dataframe with several million rows.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any experience with bigquery, but you could try changing the chunk size parameter in to_gbq().  The default is 10k.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.gbq.to_gbq.html

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery supports partial success on batched insertions. From the reply, it looks like row 90 failed to insert with reason "timeout". See "Success HTTP response codes" at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#troubleshooting for a description of the response.

If you are using an insert id you can simply retry the failed rows, or retry the full request if desired (though each retried row will count against your table quota). Retries should follow an exponential back-off pattern.